# boto s3 Bucket versus get_bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I try to access a key inside a bucket, for which I don't have permissions, though I do for the key.
In order to be able to do `get_key('this/is/my_key')`, I need the bucket object:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(key, secret_key)
my_bucket = conn.get_bucket('a_bucket')
```

yields `S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden`.

On the other hand, the following works

```
my_bucket = boto.s3.bucket.Bucket(conn, 'a_bucket')
my_bucket.get_key('this/is/my_key')
```

**Question:** What is the difference between creating the object `Bucket` and using the `get_bucket` method?
Checking the [docu](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.connection.S3Connection.get_bucket) I only see the check for validation. Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation (`validate=True` default) in the `get_bucket` checks for bucket's existence when called. Since you don't have access to the bucket, your request is turned down (403). In the other case, the class instantiation doesn't seem to do the validation, hence the `get_key` method works as intended.

Comment: yeah.. looks like this is the only difference. with `validate=False` is works

Answer (score 1):

get_bucket() need s3:listObject permission

get_key() only need s3:GetObject permission

Thus following line DOES NOT create any bucket.

```
my_bucket = boto.s3.bucket.Bucket(conn, 'a_bucket')
```

It just create a python object class pointing to the bucket. There is no error as long as you didn't perform any bucket related task. If you can do a get_key() without error, it's mean you are given the  s3:GetObject permission to the bucket.