# Can't get s3 bucket 403 due to InvalidAccessKey but works from CLI

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to access an S3 bucket through boto and getting a 403. This code:

```
from boto.s3.connection import  S3Connection
conn = S3Connection()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket')
files = bucket.list()
```

Is returning a 403 at the get_bucket line (I've stripped the values)

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id you 
    provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>*** </AWSAccessKeyId>
    <RequestId>***</RequestId>
    <HostId>***</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have seen answers about setting validate=False like this one [boto s3 Bucket versus get_bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717551/boto-s3-bucket-versus-get-bucket) but then I get the same error on the next line when trying to list the bucket.

If I run the CLI command

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket
```

I get a list of the contents.

If I run

```
aws configure list --profile default
```

The configure contains the *exact same* access ID that is in the error message in the XML. No other profiles exist, so I am wondering how it is working with the exact same key from the CLI but not boto.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using federated access and a comment buried on an AWS forum helped me.

If you are using federated users with boto you need to pass in the security token as well. The default constructor S3Connection() does not pass this, so you need to do it yourself:

```
conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id='YOURKEYID', 
aws_secret_access_key='YOURSECRETKEY', security_token='YOURTOKEN')
```

Then it works.